# GetScrollInfo only works when visual styles are activated

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

in my current Project on WinForms with .net3.5 I imported some User32.dll functions for scrolling programmatically. I extended the TableLayoutPanel - which is ought to be scrolled.

Everything worked fine after a bit of work, but now I found out that the function

```
GetScrollInfo(this.Handle, SB_VERT, ref _si);
```

always returns *false* when Visual Styles on Windows XP are deactivated. If Visual Styles are activated (everything else than "Classic" is ok), the above mentioned function returns *true* and the correct values.

How to avoid this, or how to get the correct ScrollValues without activating Visual Styles?

PS: _si is a Struct called SCROLLINFO described in the MSDN (I am not allowed to Link to more than one Page sorry) and GetScrollInfo is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787583%28VS.85%29.aspx). *this.Handle* is the Handle of the base TableLayoutPanel.

Comment: Doesn't the `TableLayoutPanel` already support scrolling through the `AutoScroll` property? I fired up the designer, overfilled a table layout panel with controls, set AutoScroll to true and it behaved as expected...

Comment: I need to scroll in subject to mouse-movement because it's build for "old" Tablet-PCs. So it's gonna be kind of "Touch-Scroll-Implementation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little playing around with the SCROLLINFO struct I found it out on my own.

For everyone having the same problem, I had to set the *cbSize* of the SCROLLINFO struct to sizeOf(SCROLLINFO).

Something like

```
    public ScrollableExampleConstructor()
    {
        _si = new SCROLLINFO();
        _si.fMask = (uint) ScrollInfoMask.SIF_ALL;
        _si.cbSize = (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(_si);
    }
```

did the job for me.

Thanks to everyone thinking about my problem!